# trying to send querystring parameters to another page using reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

I am trying to send  querystring parameters to another page using history object in the button click event like as below

```
const viewChange = (record) => {
debugger;
history.push('/Viewchange?id=record.id&dataid=record.dataid');
};
```

and this is route where i have defined in routes.js file

```
{
  path: '/Viewchange/:id/:dataid',
  exact: true,
  title: 'Viewchange',
  icon: 'dashboard',
  breadcrumbs: ['dashboard'],
  contentComponent: ViewChangeRequest,
  isEnabled: () => false,
},
```

some how i am getting an empty page with url below

`http://localhost:3000/Viewchange?id=record.id&dataid=record.dataid#`

I am not sure where i am doing wrong in this case, Could any one please let me know how to attach querystring values to url
the below code is the component which i am going to redirect

```
 const ViewChangeRequest = (props) => {
  };
  export default withRouter(ViewChangeRequest);
```

many thanks in advance

complete route.js code

```
   [
    {
      path: '/',
      exact: true,
      title: 'Dashboard',
      icon: 'dashboard',
      breadcrumbs: ['Dashboard'],
      contentComponent: UserDashboard,
      isEnabled: () => true,
    },
    {
      type: 'subMenu',
      title: 'Codes and Guidelines',
      children: [
        {
          path: '/LocalCodes',
          exact: true,
          title: 'Local Codes',
          icon: 'dashboard',
          breadcrumbs: ['Codes and Guidelines', 'Local Codes'],
          contentComponent: AddLocalCode,
          isEnabled: () => true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      type: 'subMenu',
      title: 'Design Criteria',
      children: [
        {
          path: '/Climate',
          exact: true,
          title: 'Climate',
          icon: 'dashboard',
          breadcrumbs: ['Design Criteria', 'Climate'],
          contentComponent: ContentClimate,
          isEnabled: () => true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '/Viewchange/:id/:dataid',
      title: 'Viewchange',
      icon: 'dashboard',
      breadcrumbs: ['dashboard'],
      contentComponent: ViewChangeRequest,
      isEnabled: () => false,
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backtick character ([template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) to dynamically construct your url.

```
history.push(`/Viewchange?id=${record.id}&dataid=${record.dataid}`);
```

Comment: it is redirecting to the page but it is giving blank page with the url like this `http://localhost:3000/Viewchange?id=34daf76e9e6043238bd1725a347af8d4&dataid=96a83572aec2425a8e8ee75afbf52bd3#`

Comment: @EnigmaState it is related with your route definitions. Can you add your react-router-dom route definitions?

Comment: @EnigmaState is this a configuration file for your routes? How do you use it? Can you add to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204264/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-enigma-state).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to construct dynamic Urls:

1. Using Strings - `history.push('/Viewchange?id=' + record.id + '&dataid=' + record.dataid);`
2. Using Bactick -

```
history.push(`/Viewchange?id=${record.id}&dataid=${record.dataid}`);
```